# How to properly scale web page according to screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a psd of web page and it is designed in 1920x1080 resolution.

Standard laptop and desktop has the resolution of 1366x768.

I already convert psd to html in 1366 resolution using [Skelton CSS](http://getskeleton.com/)

Now how can I scale up/down the dimension of elements like if I am writing style for 1920x1080 and matching element spacing according to psd and when viewing in 1366 resolution it should look exactly same as psd.

Like [RetinaJS](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) which easily scale up/down the images according to screen size.

Is there any framework or method by which we can easily change the view?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are searchig for [Responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Comment: I know what is responsive web design, i want the exact same look in all desktop resolution  or we can say same spacing which  increase & decrease proportionally according to screen.

Comment: You can achieve this with media queries and basic responsive coding techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different techniques to achieve your goal. As mentioned by @Jose M and @WizardCoder, you can use CSS's media query or you can use Bootstrap framework to scale your image according to screen size. Bootstrap's "img-responsive" class will do justice to your image. It will scale down your image on any screen.

Comment: hmm!  i have to use lots of media queries... but i am not using bootstrap here because its a minimal user interface project so i just want the basic rwd thats why i choose skelton css.